# Postgres convert integer into time

Tags: postgresql

I need to convert the following (hh)integer column into a time column. Expected results below:

```
hh     time
1      00:00
2      00:30
3      01:00
4      01:30
...
48     23:30
```

Can you help?

Comment: That's the 4th half hour out of the 48 half hours.

Comment: `select (make_interval(mins := (hh-1)*30))::time;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do:

```
select hh, ('00:00:00'::time + (hh - 1) * interval '30 minute') as time
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Use `INTERVAL` arithmetic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

```
SELECT 
  TIME '00:00' + (1 - 1) * INTERVAL '30 minutes',
  TIME '00:00' + (2 - 1) * INTERVAL '30 minutes',
  TIME '00:00' + (3 - 1) * INTERVAL '30 minutes',
  TIME '00:00' + (4 - 1) * INTERVAL '30 minutes',
  TIME '00:00' + (5 - 1) * INTERVAL '30 minutes',
  -- ...
  TIME '00:00' + (48 - 1) * INTERVAL '30 minutes'
```

Another solution would be to work with unix timestamps:

```
SELECT 
  (to_timestamp((1 - 1) * 30 * 60) at time zone 'UTC')::time,
  (to_timestamp((2 - 1) * 30 * 60) at time zone 'UTC')::time,
  (to_timestamp((3 - 1) * 30 * 60) at time zone 'UTC')::time,
  (to_timestamp((4 - 1) * 30 * 60) at time zone 'UTC')::time,
  (to_timestamp((5 - 1) * 30 * 60) at time zone 'UTC')::time,
  -- ...
  (to_timestamp((48 - 1) * 30 * 60) at time zone 'UTC')::time
```